# How do you move a circle in python?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a circle that moves but I don't know how to make it work. I am using pygame as the package. I think it'll work if you update the circle but I don't know how to do that.

```
import os, sys, math, pygame, pygame.mixer
from pygame.locals import *

black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
white = (255,255,255)
run_me = True

screen_size = screen_width, screen_height = 600, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption('ha ha ha ha ha')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps_limit = 60

#circle 
    colorcircle = (red)
    posx = 300
    posy = 200
    circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorcircle, (posx, posy), 50)

while run_me:
    clock.tick(fps_limit) 


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run_me = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                posx = posx - 10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                posx = posx + 10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                posy = posy + 10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                posy = posy - 10

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

I want the  to circle move somewhere depending on input.

However, the circle does nothing!

Answer (score 4):

To move the circle, you have to redraw it every frame.
To do so, add the following to lines to your while loop (just before `pygame.display.flip()`)

```
# fill the screen with black (otherwise, the circle will leave a trail)
screen.fill(black)
# redraw the circle
pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorcircle, (posx, posy), 50)
```